# How to insert data in Sequelize

Tags: express, mariadb, sequelize.js

In my Express app, I have to insert a new table record to MySQL database. I'm using Sequelize as the ORM. However, with the following setup , I couldn't do that. When I send a POST request to `/users/register` method(`UserController.signup()` is set to be executed at this route), it is waiting forever for a response in POSTman. I tried returning a string from `UserController.signup()` and then the request was working fine.

Why can't I insert a record into database? Every help is highly appreciated.

**UserController.js**

```
var User = require('../models/user')

module.exports = {
    signUp: (fname,email,password) => {
        User.create({ firstName: fname, email: email, password: password }).then(user => {
            console.log("New auto-generated ID:", user.id);
          });
    }
}
```

**models/user.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  User.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return User;
};
```

**app.js**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var db = require('./database')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var Router = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(Router);

db.authenticate()
.then(() => {
  console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
})
.catch(err => {
  console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  res.status(err.status || 500);
});

module.exports = app;
```

**database.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('test', 'root', '', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mariadb'
});

module.exports = sequelize
```

**EDIT**

I changed `models/user.js` as follows.

```
'use strict';
var sequelize = require('../database')
var Sequelize = require('sequelize')

const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  firstName: Sequelize.STRING,
  email: Sequelize.STRING,
  password: Sequelize.STRING
}, {});
User.associate = function(models) {
  // associations can be defined here
};

module.exports = User;
```

Comment: Add `catch` and see what error you get.

Comment: I changed `models/User.js` as I've mentioned in the question under EDIT and it worked properly. But the User model I posted first is the one sequelize cli defined for me. How can I use that without error?

Answer (score -1):

Add an id attribute to your User model. You're trying to access the value from the User model but it's not declared. It will still be auto-generated for you. Try something like this:

**Model user.js**

```
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
}, {});
```

**Migration** `migration:generate --name createUser`

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
  }
```

Comment: The code under **EDIT** worked for me, but I want to know why the previous code didn't work. Can you provide an explanation about the previous code? because that code was automatically generated by `sequelize-cli`.

Comment: Your first attempt is using DataTypes.type and the second is using Sequelize.type. From my experience, Sequelize.type is used in the migration file when first creating the table and DataTypes is used in the model file.